# C# regex replace of numbers and units

Tags: c#, regex, string

Have a number of product names with sizes in.

For example "X 300g", "X 400 g", "X 250 kg", "X 25kg".

Now I would like to replace all instances of "NumberUnit" with "Number Unit", i.e. "300g" to "300 g", "25kg" to "25 kg", etc.

I know I can do that easily with a loop and a string replace, but there are millions of products and I worry it would take to long to do it that way.

Instead, I guess it might be a better idea to do a Regex.Replace() on each product name.

Agree? - and how would you write the regex?

Thanks.

Comment: [The 30 Minute Regex Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-Minute-Regex-Tutorial) read this article and  in the question give some code that you have tried already.

Comment: Show us that you have made some effort to do that. Where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
(?<=\d)(?=[a-zA-Z])
```

The previous regex will capture the location between numbers and units **only** if they don't have a space in between. You can replace this location with a space, and you will be done.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/yry7Sl/3

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    string pattern = @"(?<=\d)(?=[a-zA-Z])";
    string substitution = @" ";
    string input = @"""X 300g"", ""X 400 g"", ""X 250 kg"", ""X 25kg""";

    Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
    string result = regex.Replace(input, substitution);
```